# Pandas Dataframe to Json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've this line of code made with pandas:

```
sqltable2 = sqltable.groupby(['Grupo_Resolutor', 'Sub_Estado']).size()
```

with this output

```
Grupo_Resolutor            Sub_Estado
ANALISIS DE CREDITO        CANCELADO                                2
                           MAL ESCALADO                            22
                           NO PROCEDE                            1120
                           NO PROCEDE RECONEXION                   41
                           SOLUCIONADO                           4446
                           SOLUCIONADO POR MASIVO               11898
COBRANZAS                  MAL ESCALADO                             2
                           NO PROCEDE                             203
                           NO PROCEDE COBRO                        39
                           NO PROCEDE POR MI PUNTO              21758
                           NO PROCEDE RECONEXION                   32
                           SOLUCIONADO                            533
                           SOLUCIONADO POR MIPUNTO              11966
```

And i wish to parse that groupby object to json but when i do:
(i need it with records because its for amcharts)

```
sqltable2.to_json(orient = 'records')
```

i have this output:

```
[2,22,1120,41,4446,11898,2,203,39,21758,32,533,11966]
```

desire output:

```
[
  {
    "Grupo Resolutor": "Analisis de Credito",
    "CANCELADO": 2,
    "MAL ESCALADO": 22,
    "NO PROCEDE": 1120,
    "NO PROCEDE RECONEXION": 2,
    "SOLUCIONADO": 22,
    "SOLUCIONADO POR MASIVO": 1120
  },
  {
    "Grupo Resolutor": "Cobranzas",
    "MAL ESCALADO": "2",
    "NO PROCEDE": 203,
    "NO PROCEDE COBRO": 39,
    "NO PROCEDE POR MI PUNTO": 21758,
    "NO PROCEDE RECONEXION": 32,
    "SOLUCIONADO": 533,
    "SOLUCIONADO POR MIPUNTO": 11966
  }
]
```

And so on with each 'Grupo_Resolutor' (there are more but i cant put too much code on the question)

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add first level values to `DataFrame` with [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.append.html):

```
a = sqltable2.index.levels[0]
df = sqltable2.append(pd.Series(a, index = [a,['Grupo_Resolutor'] * len(a)]))
print (df)
Grupo_Resolutor      Sub_Estado             
ANALISIS DE CREDITO  CANCELADO                                    2
                     MAL ESCALADO                                22
                     NO PROCEDE                                1120
                     NO PROCEDE RECONEXION                       41
                     OLUCIONADO                                4446
                     SOLUCIONADO POR MASIVO                   11898
COBRANZAS            MAL ESCALADO                                 2
                     NO PROCEDE                                 203
                     NO PROCEDE COBRO                            39
                     NO PROCEDE POR MI PUNTO                  21758
                     NO PROCEDE RECONEXION                       32
                     SOLUCIONADO                                533
                     SOLUCIONADO POR MIPUNTO                  11966
ANALISIS DE CREDITO  Grupo_Resolutor            ANALISIS DE CREDITO
COBRANZAS            Grupo_Resolutor                      COBRANZAS
```

And then create `dictionary` by `list comprehension`:

```
d = [v.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_dict() for k,v in df.groupby(level=0)]
```

---

```
print (d)

[{
    'Grupo_Resolutor': 'ANALISIS DE CREDITO',
    'NO PROCEDE': 1120,
    'SOLUCIONADO POR MASIVO': 11898,
    'MAL ESCALADO': 22,
    'NO PROCEDE RECONEXION': 41,
    'OLUCIONADO': 4446,
    'CANCELADO': 2
}, {
    'NO PROCEDE COBRO': 39,
    'SOLUCIONADO POR MIPUNTO': 11966,
    'NO PROCEDE': 203,
    'SOLUCIONADO': 533,
    'NO PROCEDE POR MI PUNTO': 21758,
    'NO PROCEDE RECONEXION': 32,
    'Grupo_Resolutor': 'COBRANZAS',
    'MAL ESCALADO': 2
}]
```

Last for write `dict` to `json` file use `json.dump`:

```
import json

with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(d, fp)
```

There is also possible write to `json` directly, but get `null` for values for categories which missing in some column:

```
j = df.unstack().to_json(orient='records')
print (j)

[{
    "CANCELADO": 2,
    "Grupo_Resolutor": "ANALISIS DE CREDITO",
    "MAL ESCALADO": 22,
    "NO PROCEDE": 1120,
    "NO PROCEDE COBRO": null,
    "NO PROCEDE POR MI PUNTO": null,
    "NO PROCEDE RECONEXION": 41,
    "OLUCIONADO": 4446,
    "SOLUCIONADO": null,
    "SOLUCIONADO POR MASIVO": 11898,
    "SOLUCIONADO POR MIPUNTO": null
}, {
    "CANCELADO": null,
    "Grupo_Resolutor": "COBRANZAS",
    "MAL ESCALADO": 2,
    "NO PROCEDE": 203,
    "NO PROCEDE COBRO": 39,
    "NO PROCEDE POR MI PUNTO": 21758,
    "NO PROCEDE RECONEXION": 32,
    "OLUCIONADO": null,
    "SOLUCIONADO": 533,
    "SOLUCIONADO POR MASIVO": null,
    "SOLUCIONADO POR MIPUNTO": 11966
}]
```

Comment: Almost... i didn't know about unstack, but it's ignoring Grupo_Resolutor @jezrael

Comment: Great! it works, I'm sorry i didn't replay yesterday